# Function keeps running although it shoudn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a `on ended` for video player, like this:

```
 $('.vast').on('ended', function() {
     $('.vast').removeClass('vast');
     Player.constructPlayer(
         '//techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
         '//techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm'
     );
 });
```

My problem is, even when I remove the `vast` class, it's still running in loop. What can I do?

Comment: try `$('.vast').off('ended')`

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar probably won't work, since if someone plays then stops the video it'll remove the bind, so next time they play and stop the video, there is no listener

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The event has nothing to do with the class you used to bind it. You need to remove the event handler itself.

```
$(this).off('ended');
```

Comment: Any example of how to do it? I tried `unbind()` but it didn't help.

Comment: I think this should do it. On mobile, sry